# How can I make my array a JSON array?

Tags: php, json

I have some problem with JSON. How can I make my array `"$notify_id"` a JSON array? Cause when I run my push web application it will answer me "`Field 'data' must be a JSON array: {"registration_id":["14096543677114293"]}` ".

Please help

```
   function insertNotificationStartTime($registration_id) {
        $timestamp = time();
        $start_notify = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($registration_id); $i++) {
            $random = rand(1, 10000000);
            $query = "INSERT INTO notify (id,registration_id,start_notify) VALUES ('" .$timestamp.$random. "','" .$registration_id[$i]. "','" .$start_notify. "')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            $notify_id[] = $timestamp.$random;
        }
        return $notify_id;
    }
```

Comment: `return json_encode($notify_id);`

Comment: Read up on [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: As per your example JSON at the top, you'll need to `echo json_encode(array('registration_id' => $notify_id));`

Answer (score 1):

you have to send Json header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($notify_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

> simply add

echo json_encode($notify_id);

> at end of your code this function print array of your data..in your
>   browser u must have json viewer extension so u can view your json data
>   as array..
>
> use this link
>
> [1]: http://jsonlint.com/
>
> put your code page link in that box check
>   whether your json program is right or wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
json_encode($notify_id);
```

If you get an error, Verify that the output is valid json at http://jsonlint.com.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the function is returning an array, and you have to pass to `json_encode` the result of this function.

```
$result = insertNotificationStartTime($registration_id);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Please have a look on [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function

Answer (score 0):

Script for backward-compatibility: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

And call:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

**Note**: The JSON object is now part of most modern web browsers (IE 8 & above). See caniuse for full listing.